# Double For Loop to Populate 2D Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, shapely

I'm relatively new to Python and having trouble figuring out how to populate a 2D array (a matrix) with output from a double for loop.

I have 24 shapely polygons in a list called "triangles". Some of these triangles are adjacent to each other, as you can see. I have plotted the centroids as numbers for reference.

[image]

I am interested in populating a matrix based on whether triangles are adjacent to each other or not. For example, polygon 0 is adjacent to polygons 1, 2, and 10. By hand, as a Boolean, the first line of this matrix would be:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
0   T T               T
1
...
```

Rather than just a Boolean output, I'd like to get the index of the adjacent polygon. Like:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
0   1 2               10
1
...
```

I think I will need a double for loop that looks something like:

```
flower_matrix = []
for i in range(len(triangles)):
    for j in range(len(triangles)):
         if j is adjacent to i, then write index in matrix
```

I could do this by hand, but of course I'd rather not!

Any suggestions?! Thanks for looking!

The code to generate the triangles is below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
from shapely.ops import unary_union, polygonize
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm
import numpy as np

def plot_coords(coords, color):
    pts = list(coords)
    x, y = zip(*pts)
    # print(color)
    plt.plot(x,y, color='k', linewidth=1)
    plt.fill_between(x, y, facecolor=color)


def plot_polys(polys, color):
    for poly, color in zip(polys, color):
        plot_coords(poly.exterior.coords, color)

x = 0
y = 0
h = 1.73205080757

points = [# center
          Point(x, y),
          #  first ring
          Point((x + 2), y),
          Point((x - 2), y),
          Point((x + 1), (y + h)),
          Point((x - 1), (y + h)),
          Point((x + 1), (y - h)),
          Point((x - 1), (y - h)),
          # second ring
          Point((x + 3), h),
          Point((x - 3), h),
          Point((x + 3), -h),
          Point((x - 3), -h),
          Point((x + 2), (h + h)),
          Point((x - 2), (h + h)),
          Point((x + 2), (-h + -h)),
          Point((x - 2), (-h + -h)),
          Point((x + 4), y),
          Point((x - 4), y),
          Point(x, (h + h)),
          Point(x, (-h + -h)),
          #third ring
          Point((x + 4), (h + h)),
          Point((x - 4), (h + h)),
          Point((x + 4), (-h + -h)),
          Point((x - 4), (-h + -h)),
          Point((x + 1), (h + h + h)),
          Point((x - 1), (h + h + h)),
          Point((x + 1), (-h + -h + -h)),
          Point((x - 1), (-h + -h + -h)),
          Point((x + 5), h),
          Point((x - 5), h),
          Point((x + 5), -h),
          Point((x - 5), -h)]

# buffer points to create circle polygons

circles = []
for point in points:
    circles.append(point.buffer(2))


# unary_union and polygonize to find overlaps

rings = [LineString(list(pol.exterior.coords)) for pol in circles]
union = unary_union(rings)
result_polys = [geom for geom in polygonize(union)]

# remove tiny sliver polygons
threshold = 0.01
filtered_polys = [polygon for polygon in result_polys if polygon.area > threshold]

# remove outer circle fragments
complete_polys = [polygon for polygon in filtered_polys if (polygon.centroid.x**2 + polygon.centroid.y**2 < 4**2)]

print("total polygons = " + str(len(result_polys)))
print("filtered polygons = " + str(len(filtered_polys)))
print("complete polygons = " + str(len(complete_polys)))

centroidCoords = [
    Point(0.9999999999999997, -0.5773635180985456),
    Point(1.5000000000000004, -0.866025403785),
    Point(1.9999999999999987, -1.154687289471454),
    Point(0, -1.1546872894714544),
    Point(0, -1.7320508075699992),
    Point(-0.0000000000000002, -2.3094143256685467),
    Point(-1.0000000000000004, -0.577363518098546),
    Point(-1.5, -0.8660254037850001),
    Point(-1.9999999999999996, -1.154687289471454),
    Point(-1, 0.5773635180985459),
    Point(-1.5000000000000004, 0.8660254037850001),
    Point(-1.9999999999999993, 1.1546872894714537),
    Point(-0.0000000000000001, 1.1546872894714542),
    Point(0, 1.73205080757),
    Point(0.0000000000000001, 2.309414325668546),
    Point(1, 0.5773635180985456),
    Point(1.5000000000000002, 0.8660254037849999),
    Point(1.9999999999999993, 1.1546872894714542),
    Point(2.9999999999999987, -0.5773635180985457),
    Point(3.5, -0.8660254037849997),
    Point(2, -1.73205080757),
    Point(1.9999999999999996, -2.309414325668546),
    Point(0.5, -0.8660254037850001),
    Point(0.5, 0.866025403785),
    Point(2, 1.7320508075700005),
    Point(2.0000000000000004, 2.3094143256685467),
    Point(3.0000000000000004, 0.5773635180985458),
    Point(3.4999999999999996, 0.8660254037849999),
    Point(-0.5000000000000001, -0.866025403785),
    Point(-2.0000000000000004, -1.7320508075699999),
    Point(-2.000000000000001, -2.3094143256685475),
    Point(-3.000000000000001, -0.5773635180985459),
    Point(-3.500000000000001, -0.866025403785),
    Point(-3.0000000000000018, 0.5773635180985461),
    Point(-3.4999999999999987, 0.8660254037849999),
    Point(-2.0000000000000004, 1.73205080757),
    Point(-1.9999999999999996, 2.3094143256685467),
    Point(-0.5, 0.8660254037849999),
    Point(2.5, 0.866025403785),
    Point(1, 0),
    Point(-0.5000000000000001, 2.5980762113550004),
    Point(-0.9999999999999994, 2.886738097041452),
    Point(1.0000000000000009, 2.8867380970414565),
    Point(0.9999999999999997, 3.4641016151399993),
    Point(2.5000000000000004, 2.598076211355),
    Point(-0.9999999999999997, 0),
    Point(-2.5, 0.8660254037850001),
    Point(-2.500000000000001, 2.598076211355001),
    Point(-0.9999999999999999, 3.4641016151399993),
    Point(0.4999999999999998, 2.5980762113549987),
    Point(2.5000000000000004, -2.598076211355),
    Point(1.0000000000000002, -2.8867380970414547),
    Point(1.0000000000000002, -3.4641016151400006),
    Point(-0.5, -2.598076211355001),
    Point(-0.9999999999999997, -2.8867380970414533),
    Point(2.5000000000000004, -0.8660254037850001),
    Point(0.5, -2.598076211355),
    Point(-0.9999999999999992, -3.464101615139999),
    Point(-2.5, -2.598076211355001),
    Point(-2.5000000000000004, -0.8660254037850001),
    Point(3, 0),
    Point(1.5000000000000002, 2.5980762113550004),
    Point(-3.0000000000000004, 0),
    Point(-1.4999999999999998, 2.5980762113549987),
    Point(1.4999999999999998, -2.598076211355001),
    Point(-1.5, -2.598076211355)]


# separating into petals and triangles

limit = 0.66

triangles = [polygon for polygon in complete_polys if polygon.area < limit]
petals = [polygon for polygon in complete_polys if polygon.area > limit]


for i in range(len(triangles)):
    plot_coords(triangles[i].exterior.coords, triangles_colors[i])
    centroidCoords = triangles[i].centroid
    plt.scatter(centroidCoords.x,centroidCoords.y, marker="$"+str(i)+"$")
    
print(len(triangles))
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: seems like a DFS or BFS algorithm problem

Comment: I don't know what that means

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: This seems like an algorithm question not a programming one. You could try to get an answer on [math.se] or [cs.se] but questions asking for help developing an algorithm really aren’t on topic here.